# Query table based on a value in FK

Tags: ios, core-data, foreign-key-relationship, predicate

I have a couple of  tables:

```
User:
  - userId (NString)
  - name (NSString)

Report: 
  - reportName (NSString)
  - user (foreign key to user table)
```

I have a userId and I want to get all reports for that user.  Do I have to query for the user first from core data?

If so this is bad as I am trying to implement find and update logic as outline by apple.  In my case I only have one report per user.  I am getting back an array of reports from the server and each report contains a userId (assigned by server).  If I don't have a report for that user yet I need to create one.  If I have report for that user I need to update with the new report.

So basically I create an array of NSString (userId's) to use in a predicate:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Report" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(userId IN %@)", userIds]];
```

However in this case userId does not really exist, user is a foreign relationship.

I could not make a foreign relationship and just store userId in report but then I need to manually join later.  Is that a better option.

Comment: Can you clarify, is `user` on report a Core Data relationship, or a SQL-style foreign key? You refer to it in both ways.

Comment: Sorry, it's a core data relationship. Which makes it way new to me and confusing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of a foreign key does not exist in Core Data. Sure, they're used for one of the possible backing stores, but the foreign key is hidden. In its place, we have instead a relationship.

If you have a relationship established, you just walk the keypath. No further fetch is necessary.

You need inverses for your relationships. So if a Report has a User, the User has Reports.

For your purposes, I suggest implementing a `reportWithReportName:` (does a fetch), `findOrCreateWithReportName:` (tries a fetch, does an insert if necessary), `userWithUserID:` (does a fetch), and `findOrCreateUserWithUserID:name:` (fetch, insert if needed).

```
Report *aReport;
User *someUser;

NSLog(@"%@", aReport.user.name, aReport.user.userID);
NSLog (@"%@", someUser.userID, someUser.reports);
foreach (Report *report in someUser.reports) {
    NSLog(@"%@", report.reportName);
}
```

Comment: Yup seems very easy now that you outline it ;)  Get the users and use the inverse relationship to update the reports.  Thanks!